# Is it possible to enable Javascript in a standalone JavaFX desktop application?

Tags: javascript, java, javafx

I'm trying to build a javafx desktop application that make use of Javascript to handle some GUI events. But I'm getting an error.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
    <?language javascript?>
    
    <Label  fx:id="me"
            text="I am old "
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            onMouseClicked="sayHello()" >
        <fx:script>
            function sayHello() {
            me.setText("Hello from FXML!");
            }
        </fx:script>
    </Label>
```

Here's the error

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Page language not specified.
/C:/Users/mudzi/Desktop/codeAll/codeJava/codeJavaFX/projectLearn/target/classes/org/codeME/inside.fxml:15
/C:/Users/mudzi/Desktop/codeAll/codeJava/codeJavaFX/projectLearn/target/classes/org/codeME/childStage.fxml:17
```

I can't understand the error please help. What is page language and how to specify it.

Comment: [This](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#scripting) seems like a good place to start.